# List casting interface is failing in Java

Tags: java

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface CustomWebElement extends WebElement
. . . methods
```

In the following places, when I try to cast `WebElement` to `CustomWebElement` things are fine:

```
CustomWebElement a = (CustomWebElement) element.findElement(by); //findElement return WebElement
```

but the calls to `findElements` method which returns `List<WebElement>` casting is failing:

```
List<CustomWebElement> a = (List<CustomWebElement>) element.findElements(by);
```

giving me exception:

```
Inconvertable types; Cannot cast List<WebElement> to List<CustomWebElement>
```

why `List` cast is failing in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List<WebElement>` is an object type in its own right as is `List<CustomWebElement>`, and `List<CustomWebElement>` does not extend `List<WebElement>`

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

`CustomWebElement extends WebElement` does NOT mean that `List<CustomWebElement> extends List<WebElement>`

Answer (score 0):

It is because `List<WebElement>` is neither a subtype nor supertype of `List<CustomWebElement>`.  For more information, you can read Item25 from Effective Java of Joshua Bloch. I am copying and pasting from his book

> Arrays differ from generic types in two important ways. First, arrays are covariant.
>   This scary-sounding word means simply that if Sub is a subtype of Super, then the
>   array type Sub[] is a subtype of Super[]. Generics, by contrast, are invariant: for
>   any two distinct types Type1 and Type2, List is neither a subtype nor a
>   supertype of List

Answer (score 0):

Use of wildcards while using generics may help
Like

> List<**? extends WebElement**>